# Change logon credential of all the services with like operator in name in windows 2016 server in bulk

Tags: powershell, wmi

I want to change logon credential of all the windows services with like operator in name in windows 2016 server in bulk using powershell or wmi.

Answer (score 0):

$account="domain\account"

$password="password"

$svc=gwmi win32_service -filter "name LIKE '%abcd%"

$svc.StopService();

$result = $svc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$false,$account,$password,$null,$null,$null)

if ($result.ReturnValue -eq '0') {write-host "Password changed"} else {write-host "Error: $result.ReturnValue"};

$svc.StartService();